# Is it possible to use Visual Studio as an IDE for Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: java, visual-studio, ide, gwt

As a long time user of Visual Studio, I feel comfortable using this as my primary IDE for editing code (I primarily code in C#/ASP.NET). Lately I've been looking more in depth into the Google Web Toolkit (or GWT) as a potential tool for building rapid web client tools for the web. I would therefore like to know whether it is possible to edit Java syntax, and otherwise set Visual Studio up to built web applications for GWT?

Comment: You're better off with eclipse gwt plugins - believe me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option i m using is using Eclipse with an IntelliJ Idea key mapping ( i m  a resharper fan and I miss it)
Another option is take the plunge and get IntelliJ Idea, its a fantastic IDE and it was really easy to get used to it, it has some nice pluggins for GWT development too

Cheers

Comment: Based on the answers to this questions, I must conclude that it is not possible to use Visual Studio as an IDE for GWT.

Answer (score 0):

What is Visual Studio's support for Java like, I assuming that its GWT support is not as good. ;)

I think you are better off using an IDE which actually supports GWT. 
You could have a look at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gwt.html The demo is rather old (from 2006) but if you haven't seen IntelliJ it might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio used to be the best Java IDE in the 90's.
Since then much better alternatives came out.

The 3 most commonly used right now are:
Eclipse
NetBeans
IntelliJ.

Microsoft stopped supporting Java development a long time ago. At that time Java was still at 1.3. With Java 1.5 the language was extended with generics and other constructs that Visual Studio will certainly not support.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to use Visual Studio for [Java](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93) (or maybe J# could work?), integrate [Maven](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170328/Maven-Build-for-NET-Application) in it and then use the [maven gwt plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) to translate the java to ajax, it shoooould be possible.
But this is just an idea, would probably take a lot of efford, if it works at all.